# Reuse Serilog Templates

Tags: serilog, string-interpolation

Sometimes I need to save the log message to a database.
Getting redundant code like this.

```
public async Task Timeout(StartSendTradeSaga state, IMessageHandlerContext context)
{
    var msg = $"Stale trade: Trade {Data.TradeId} has been awaiting reply for more than one hour";
    Log.Error("Stale trade: Trade {TradeId} has been awaiting reply for more than one hour", Data.TradeId);
    Data.LogStatus = LogStatus.Error;
    Data.LogMessage = msg;
    if (Data.SaharaLogId != -1)
    {
        await SaveLog();
        MarkAsComplete();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to write log to database - missing audit trail id");
    }
}
```

To create the msg I use string interpolation and in the next line I log using the Serilog template syntax.

I log to EleaticSearch in json format. So, I can't use interplolation here.

Looking for suggestions on how to only write the message once.

Comment: Serilog Captures (packages up template and all values into a ReadOnlyDictionary without forming an interpolated string as yet) the values into a LogEvent on the logging thread. Then that gets passed to the chain of sinks as configured. Each renders the LogEvent via a given MessageTemplate. You might be able to pull your custom logging logic out as a sink, and then, if it fits the criteria, render it and output it. There is no construct in Serilog for directly reusing the formatted final string, and I woulnt overthink trying to do that.